# $L^{2}_{loc}(\Omega)$ with respect to the Lebesgue meausre and $L^2$ with respect to $e^{-\phi} d\lambda$

Tags: complex-analysis

In Lars Hormander's An Introduction to Complex Analysis in Several Variables, page 77, he says that"every function in $L^2(\Omega, loc)$ belongs to  $L^2(\Omega,\phi)$ for some continuous $\phi$
, where $L^2(\Omega,\phi)$ has the measure $e^{-\phi}d\lambda$. Why is that?

$\Omega$is open and $d\lambda$ is the Lesbegue measure

Comment: If you write $\Omega = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} K_n$ where $K_n$ are a nested sequence of compact sets, could you define the appropriate $\phi$ "piecewise" on each $K_{n+1} \setminus K_n$ in a continuous way? This could be one way to do this.

Comment: I do this in another way, by ajudusting $\phi$ to the $L^2$ norm of $f$.